# Nuxt 3 routeRules for disabling SSR only for one page

Tags: vuejs3, server-side-rendering, nuxtjs3, nuxt3, client-side-rendering

I have a Vue 3 with Nuxt 3 application.

My folder structure is like this with `pages` folder being in the root:

```
-- pages/
   -- games/
      -- skills/
         -- [player].vue
   -- more-pages/
```

In my `nuxt.config.ts` file I have a property for `routeRules` and I want this changed only for one page for hybrid rendering by disabling the SSR. Currently, I have it as below:

```
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  routeRules: {
    "/pages/games/skills/**": { ssr: false },
  },
})
```

I want to disable SSR only for the `[player].vue` page. Should the `routeRules` for the page path be as above

OR should it be as below, i.e., not to explicitly mention the `/pages` folder?

```
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  routeRules: {
    "/games/skills/**": { ssr: false },
  },
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without `/pages`.

That is just the folder containing the route / path, not part of it.